# There must be/there must live

Tags: verbs

> 1 There must be more than 1000 people in this settlement for us to
> play there.
>
> 2 There must live more than 1000 people in this settlement for us to
> play there.

I have a feeling that "there must be" is correct. But "there must live" is wrong. Is it so? If I am right on it, what's the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: The 'discrepancy' is that 'there must live...' is old-fashioned and formal. _Beyond the stars there must live a gracious Father._ CF Schiller, 'Ode to Joy' _Darwin predicted that somewhere in Madagascar there must live just such an insect._

Comment: Does it mean that any verb can be used? "There must work 100 people in this plant". Correct?

Comment: That sounds like something a foreigner would say.

Comment: _There must be more than 1000 people living in this settlement_ would be more idiomatic.

Comment: *There must live five hundred people,* does sound old fashioned but only due to the word order.  The sentence is idiomatic and modern sounding if it is expressed, *Five hundred people must live there.*  That's a very common usage.  Same words.  Different order.

Comment: But in "Five hundred people must live there." there is locative while in "There must live five hundred people" there is existential

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construction "There is ..." is well known.  "There are 1000 people".

Using this construction with other verbs that express existence is possible, though rather formal or dated:

> There arose a great wind...
>
> In a cabin there lived an old woodcutter...

With other verbs the construction is even more odd.  It is not normal in modern English, though still understood.

> On the eve of midsummer, there fought the knights of Harold.

And the sense overlaps with the simple "locative" sense of "there".  As it is dated, Learners should not use this construction.

And similarly "must live" is possible, though it seems rather dated. In modern English only "There is" is common, and so "There must be" is acceptable.

"There must live 1000 people" is understandable, but rather dated, formal or marked.

Of course the *meaning* of "there are 1000 people" differs from that of "there live 1000 people", which is due to the difference in meaning between "be" and "live".

Comment: I must be old-fashioned, because I say things like 'there must exist one other person in this department who understands spreadsheets!'.

Comment: While I agree with this answer there is a point that I think everyone seems to be missing...  

There is a slight difference in meaning between "there must be" and "there must live".  
The first form simply states that people have to be present in that location, while the second one requires they actually *live* there.  
In other words: For the first statement visitors to the location count. For the second variant visitors don't count.  

It is a subtlety that is easily overlooked and probably not even intended by the person casually using the second variant.

Comment: Yes, there is a semantic difference between "be" and "live".